# Recommended plugins in d3js for state diagram

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating a project similar to state diagram in D3 js

Here's the fiddle of my sample work: http://jsfiddle.net/g8jxra96/

I want to connect different shapes with line connections either with in the svg group or outside the group.

1. It could be a line connection between circles
2. It could be a line connection between rectangles
3. It could be a line connection between circles and rectangles or paths

All the above line connections should be draggable or strechable.

Is there a plugin already available to achieve this in D3 js?
Note: the above requirement should be accomplished in only svg format